# How to delete the entire row in the database from html table instead of deleting entire table in the database

Tags: php, sql

I have added delete button to the html table on each row and when clicked on delete button the entire row should be deleted but instead whole table in the database is being deleted.

here is my code for admin.php

```
    <div class="container mt-3 ml-3">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>S.No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Rating</th>
        <th>Review</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Suggestion</th>
        <th>NPS</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-warning">

<?php
include 'database_conn.php';      // makes db connection

$sql = "SELECT feedbackID, name, email, rating, review, image, suggestion, nps
        FROM feedback 
        ORDER BY feedbackID Desc";
$queryResult = $dbConn->query($sql);

// Check for and handle query failure
if($queryResult === false) {
    echo "<p>Query failed: ".$dbConn->error."</p>\n";
    exit;
}
// Otherwise fetch all the rows returned by the query one by one
else {
    if ($queryResult->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($rowObj = $queryResult->fetch_object()) {
            echo "<tr>
                  <td>{$rowObj->feedbackID}</td>
                  <td>{$rowObj->name}</td>
                  <td>{$rowObj->email}</td>
                  <td>{$rowObj->rating}</td>
                  <td>{$rowObj->review}</td>
                  <td>{$rowObj->image}</td>
                  <td>{$rowObj->suggestion}</td>
                  <td>{$rowObj->nps}</td>
                  <td><a id='delete' href=delete.php?id={$rowObj->feedbackID}>Delete</a></td>
                  

              ";
        }

    }
}
?>

</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

And here my code for delete.php. I think there is something wrong in the sql query I made.

```
    <?php
include 'database_conn.php';      // makes db connection


$sql = "DELETE FROM feedback WHERE feedbackID=feedbackID";

if ($dbConn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully. Please go to Customer Feedback Page by clicking"; echo "<a href='http://unn-w18031735.newnumyspace.co.uk/feedback/admin.php'> here</a>";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . $dbConn->error;
}

$dbConn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Answer below details current issue. `<a id='delete'` could also be an issue down the road, `id`s should be unique. In the loop this would create multiple ids of the same name... You also should quote the `href` value as you had the `id`. e.g. `href='delete.php?id={$rowObj->feedbackID}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solution in delete.php has worked.

```
$feedbackID = $_GET["id"];
$sql = ("DELETE FROM feedback WHERE feedbackID= '$feedbackID'");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
DELETE FROM feedback WHERE feedbackID=feedbackID
```

it is always true as it will be equal to itself.

What you want to use is parameters here. $_GET['id'] is where the id is.

If you use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo), something like

```
$stmt = $dbConn->prepare("DELETE FROM feedback WHERE feedbackID=:feedback_id");
$stmt->execute(['feedback_id' => $_GET['id']]);
```

For mysqli,

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM feedback WHERE feedbackID=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute();
```